# Use Animation Nodes with texture to drive rotation

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I was wanting to create an array of circles based on the vertices of a subdivide plane that could then have the rotation of say X be driven by a 2d B@W bitmap animation. Is there a way to achieve this if the plane had a uv map with the bitmap animation as a texture.
I did see an example that used weight paint to drive position but that is not quite what I need. I'm very new to AN so apologies and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to Stackexchange! The first thing to do is to sample the values of the pixels of the image. This can be done using this small snippet of python code:

```
bpy.data.images[imageName].pixels[:][0::4]
```

We are basically making a copy of the pixel values and only getting every fourth pixel, the pixels list include the values of all four channels of the image since your image is BW, we only get one of the values, hence the `[0::4]`.

Next, we get the width and height of the image, we get the width using:

```
bpy.data.images[imageName].size[0]
```

And the height using:

```
bpy.data.images[imageName].size[1]
```

We then use the *Distribute Matrices* node to create the grid with the same width and height of the image. We use the *Axis Rotation Matrix* node to create a rotation matrix from the pixel values and multiply both matrices list. Depending on which version you are using, you will either use the *Replicate Mesh* node to replicate a unity triangle along the matrices or use the new *Transform Mesh* node to replicate the unity triangle as I will be using here. We then output that mesh and set the container object as the parent of your circle object and activate *Face Duplication* for the container object.

[image: Node Tree]

The pixels of an image have a grid structure, thus assigning the values of pixels to objects distributed on a grid is easy. If the objects are not distributed on a grid, then one would have to *guess* what the value of each object is, this is called an *Interpolation*. There are multiple types of interpolations, the simplest of which is called the *Nearest Neighbour Interpolation*, and this is what we will be using here. Basically the bounding plane of the structure is aligned with the image, then for each object, we find the closest pixel to it and assign its value to it.

Let the structure be defined by the vertices of a mesh. We imagine the image as a plane whose lower left corner is at $(0,0)$ and upper right corner at $(\text{Image Width},\text{Image Height})$. The first thing to do is normalize the vertices locations, that is, transform the vertices locations into the range $[0,1]$ in both axis:

[image: Node Tree]

See the [documentation](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/nodes/mesh/get_bounding_box.html#examples-of-usage) for more info. Then we multiply the x location by the width of the image and the y location by the height of the image, that way, the bounding plane of the structure aligns with the image we imagined. By flooring the x and y locations we get an integer representing the index of the column and row of the closest pixel to each vertex:

[image: Node Tree]

*Linear Indexing* can be used to compute the index of a pixel in a flat list knowing its column and row index, the equation is $\text{index} = iw+j$ where $i$ and $j$ are the indices of the rows and columns respectively and $w$ is the width of the image, by implementing that:

[image: Node Tree]

Now, all we have to do is sample the pixel values at those indices as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Finally, compute the matrices and use them just as we did before:

[image: Result]

Blend file for study:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I'm having a little trouble replicating the setup. I can't find a couple of the nodes you have used, these are: Unity Triangle Mesh and the Transform Mesh. Also I have not found Axis Rotation Matrix but instead used a Rotation Matrix. Not sure if that is the same. I'm also getting a "Wrong Output Type" from the expression 'bpy.data.images["Map"].pixels[:][0::4]'

Comment: @Bopstar What version are you using? I am guessing it is `2.0`. If so, can you download a [2.1 build](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/releases/tag/v2.1_testbuilds_2)? For the wrong output type, can you click on the gear button and search for *Float List*, does that fixe the problem?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to response Omar. Did manage to get 2.1 installed and working. Yes the "Float List" did the trick. But still can't get your setup to work for some reason. I'm getting a "different length" message under the Matrix Math node. Not sure what I have done or have missed. Thanks for your patience Omar.

Comment: Ok, all good now not sure what changed. However, not sure how to get the circle to attach as per you example with the monkey.

Comment: @Bopstar Can you see the triangles already? Blender can instance an object over the faces of a mesh, in this case, our triangles. Check the documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/ja/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/duplifaces.html) to see how it works. All you have to do is activate it and parent the object to the source object.

Comment: Hey Thanks Omar, I'll check that out. Thanks again for your help. Once I get it working I may need to ask a couple more questions but I'll weight to see if I can work them out without bothering you.

Comment: thanks for your help here is the result. Link: https://imgur.com/a/7OIuvgQ

Comment: is it possible to use an image sequence to drive the animation and would that need to be loaded into the movie clip editor for AN to read it. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Bopstar Blender doesn't allow the direct access of pixels of a certain frame of a video. There are workarounds, but they are very bad for Animation Nodes specifically, [see this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/how-to-read-pixels-of-a-video-from-python-api). If you don't mind, give me 15 minutes to research if there is an easy way around this. If not, I will introduce you to the standard way.

Comment: @Bopstar It seems that, if you add the video as an image sequence in a UV image editor (Don't close the UV editor) and enabling *Auto Refresh* in the image setting, and play the animation with *Always* automatic execution enabled, the node tree will work as you expect it. This is, of course, a non ideal solution, alternatively you can get the data using an external python library, *scipy* maybe.

Comment: thanks for so much for that, I'll give it a whirl and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I'm getting errors on the expression you can see in the image. Is there something I need to add or do differently? https://imgur.com/a/gAWqt78

Comment: @Bopstar Your image name is `Map2_000.png`. Your forgot the `.png` part in the expression.

Comment: your awesome! Thanks so very much for all your help.

Comment: Here is the result working https://imgur.com/a/d5hOZHa.

Comment: is there a way to do this same thing but use vertices of a mesh to define the the layout of the grid. I ask as I would like to create a circle as the base instead of a plane and I realize that images are not round. Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: I have tried to render an animation and it fails to update even though the animation will play in the view port OK and cycle though the image sequence. It seams to only use the first frame when rendering. Is there away to force it to use the other frames in the sequence when rendering?

Comment: @Bopstar 1. Yes we can, in which case, an interpolation can be used, will edit my answer to explain this concept. 2. That's why I told you this workaround is bad, because it is context sensitive. It is probable that the rendering occur in the same UV editor we are using to update the image sequence. I see two ways to fix this, either open another UV editor, select the same sequence and enable *Auto refresh*, so you have two identical UV editors opened or cache the pixels before rendering, I shall explain this in my edit as well.

Comment: @Bopstar Edited my answer. I recommend you cache the pixel values before rendering by encapsulating it in a group subprogram and invoking it using the Once Per Input caching mechanism as described in the [documentation](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/invoke.html#once-per-input). Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thanks so very much for all the information, my head is spinning. I'm having and issue with getting my map to correspond to the mesh, what might I be doing wrong here Omar. I thing it might be to do with "Index" in the "Get List Elements" after the "Object Bounding Box". Also I don't know if this is correct but your node tree showed  for the "index=iw+j" part your taking the data from the expression node for the "image [0]" and not after the Math Floor node. But when I changed it it worked.

Comment: thanks for guidance on using caching. I used a group containing just  the expression for the image pixels and Map Range node and Cached that with the Invoke Subprogram on the group https://imgur.com/a/hzoLKED

Comment: The `size[0]` is the width of the image, that is, the $w$ in our equation, that's why we used it. The $i$ and $j$ are the floored floats as you can see in the images. I added the blend file for you to study. Glad to see that caching worked for you, I will recommend that you replace the *Value Remapping Node* with a simple multiply node. To remap from $[0,1]$ to $[0,180]$ you simply multiply by $180$. Let me know if you have further inquiry.

Comment: thanks so very much for the information and Blend file, which I shall study. Already learnt heaps.

Comment: Perfect understand what the issue was thanks to your Blend file. Your awesome!

Comment: @Bopstar Happy to help. Please accept the answer if it answers your question.